# How do I get both rear brake calipers to stop sticking?

Tags: brake-calipers

I changed the rear brakes on my 2004 Chevrolet Silverado and now both brake calipers are sticking.  What causes this and how do I fix it?

Comment: When you say changed the brakes, do you mean replaced the brake pads, or the calipers themselves? Can  you go into more detail about the work you did?

Answer (score 1):

To add to user9181, when changing brake pads, its important to properly lubricate the moving parts.  If you are doing this yourself, the new pads/clips should come with a little diagram showing where to apply lubricant to the clips.  If you have a shop do the work, you can only hope they do all this.  If the caliper pistons are stuck, it is possible to rebuild these (basically, installing fresh rubber boots and cleaning up the sliding surfaces), but a new set of calipers is fairly cheap.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A brake caliper can stick because the caliper slide pins are corroded, the anti-rattle clips are corroded, or the caliper pistons are sticking (replace calipers).

Comment: Calipers can be rebuilt.  It's a little more work than just replacing, but costs less.